# Never ending while loop

Tags: c#, timer, while-loop

Here is example from one C# book:

```
//  Timer02.cs - Displaying Date and Time
//      Using the Timer class. 
//      Press Ctrl+C or 'q' folllwed by Enter to end program. 
//------------------------------------------------------------
using System;
using System.Timers;

class myApp
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DisplayTimeEvent);
        myTimer.Interval = 1000;
        myTimer.Start();


        while (Console.Read() != 'q')
        {
            ;    // do nothing...
        }
    }

    public static void DisplayTimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("\r{0}", DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

I guess that it is supposed that loops runs until q is pressed, but when q is pressed loop is not ending.

What I am missing here?

Comment: followed by Enter to end program.

Comment: You could add enter to end it, or use my example below to use it with just q key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you didn't press return after `q`. The [`Console.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.console.read.aspx) method blocks until there's an entire line to read, even though it only actually reads a single character of that line.

From the documentation:

> The Read method blocks its return while you type input characters; it terminates when you press the Enter key.

Comment: Very simple but true, as I pressed ENTER after q it did what it was supposed to do - terminate loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The method I posted never printed the message until some other key was pressed.

This will work however....

```
public static void Main()
    {
        Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DisplayTimeEvent);
        myTimer.Interval = 1000;
        myTimer.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                while (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar != 'q')
                {
                    // do nothing
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The key here is to use: Console.ReadKey().KeyChar != 'q'

Comment: That's entirely unnecessary, and irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Fixed... Sorry about that. Not really irrelevant though, if the timer was blocking it would never exit.

Comment: Thanks for providing alternative solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "If the timer was blocking"? There's no foreground thread here to stop the process from exiting.